# How to fix MODULE_NOT_FOUND in Visual Studio while trying to run Standalone Typescript Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting to create a Standalone Typescript Angular project in Visual Studio 2022 Community (17.8.0), but I am encountering the MODULE_NOT_FOUND error while running the project.

I installed 20.9.0 node version, also checked the folders, `index.js` and `init.js` are there.

How can I fix this?

[image]

I re-installed node, clean the project but still having this error.

**UPDATE:**
I saw this message in the output window.

> An exception happened at deploy, the port 4200 configured on
> launch.json is unavailable.

And here is the launch.json file

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Edge)",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Chrome)",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Angular-and-ASPNET-Core-template-error:/10512806?sort=newes
To temporary fix it, you should get an older version of angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@v16-lts
```

I will edit my answer when the fix is in place in upcoming releases.

**Edit:** Get the latest Visual Studio update or (17.8.1) and the problem is fixed.

Comment: I also tried with the 18.13.0 version but it still has the same issue. Is the magical solution v16?

Comment: I updated VS to 17.8.1 and got the same error.

Comment: Yes, I went down the same path. So far only v16 works and that's very annoying

Comment: I think they will fix this issue with version 17.9